# Jquery draggable makes input text fields uneditable (swallows onfocus?)

Tags: jquery-ui

I have written code (below) to be able to drag an input field onto another, but it seems that draggable swallows `input[text].onfocus`.

This results in the problem, that all draggable input fields act as disabled (firefox) and clicking the mouse does not focus them. I can edit the input field if I focus on them using the TAB key, but I have to traverse all the necessary tab-indexes.

So it seems draggable swallows the `input[text].onfocus` mouse event.

Is there a way to workaround this during bind-time?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() 
  {
    $("#drag-table tr td input").draggable({helper: 'clone', revert: 'invalid', cancel: null, cursor: 'move', addClasses: false, containment: $("#drag-table"), handle: 'h2', opacity: 0.8, scroll: true });
    $("#drag-table tr td input").droppable({
      addClasses: false,
      drop: function(ev, ui) {
        alert('value='+ ui.draggable.val() + ", text=" + ui.draggable.text() + " and deeper=" + ui.draggable[0].value);
        $(this).insertAtCaret(ui.draggable.val());
        ui.draggable.val(null);
        $(this).trigger('change');
      }
    });
  });

  $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
    return this.each(function(){
        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
        //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
        else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = this.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
            this.focus();
            this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this.value += myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
    });
  };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" id="drag-table">
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="1x1y" id="id1x1y" value="text" onfocus="alert('onfocus swallowed?');"/></td> 
  <td><input type="text" name="2x1y" id="id2x1y" onchange="alert('hello');"/></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="1x2y" id="id1x2y" value="next"/></td> 
  <td><input type="text" name="2x2y" id="id2x2y"/></td> 
  </tr>
  </table>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the element in either a div or span (depending on which would be valid) and apply the draggable event on that instead.