# text fields becoming non-editable when used in jquery ui draggables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery draggable UI dialog plugins in my page like the one in the shown image.

[image]

In the image, the area's that are marked in yellow color are all sortable and draggable. the textboxes marked in red color are not editable in firefox only. this works fine withtout any problem in chrome browser.

kindly suggest the right fix for firefox.

Comment: Please post your code and/or an example on jsFiddle.net.

Comment: Guess it's the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695591/jquery-draggable-makes-input-text-fields-uneditable-swallows-onfocus

Comment: @ChrisBenseler: I want to make the textbox and the label to be draggable. These contents are dynamically generated. How do i do that. i.e. being draggable and editable. Kindly give hint to resolve

Comment: @ChrisBenseler: This issue is not occuring when using jQuery UI 1.7.2 and the issue is faced in jQuery UI 1.8.13. I think its a jquery bug